# How to send commands from android to pc with windows over USB

Tags: android, windows, usb

I am working on a project where I need to establish a communication between an Android device and a PC with windows OS. It's going to be an app that has a few buttons with each one of these buttons representing a command that a app on the pc side must do.

There's a problem, however. I need to do this connection through usb cable, without internet, without bluetooth and without adb also. I managed to do this with adb but I can't use it on my project.

I've been searching a lot for a solution, but with no success. The closest I got was that I need to implement the Android Open Accessory Protocol on the pc side, but no one seems to have done this yet for me to get at least an example to guide me.

I don't even know if it's possible to turn the pc in a android accessory. I looked for libusb too, but it doesn't seems to work with android devices. 
So, does anyone here can shed some light on me? I am lost. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. On PC I used library usb4java, which is a libusb implementation in java, and used Android Open Accessory Protocol to establish the communication.